# Where are the osx commands stored?

Tags: macos, terminal, nstask

I'm writing a mac app (osx 10.9) that accesses the terminal commands using NSTask and I wanted to run some of the commands from my app. Where are the terminal commands (gcc, mkdir,git) stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which` to determine this:

```
% which gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
% which mkdir
/bin/mkdir
% which git
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 1):

They can be scattered all over the place. You can see where individual commands are by using `which`

```
which mv
/bin/mv
```

Also, you can see what are all the paths that are used to search for a given command with the following:

```
echo $PATH
```